# How to loop throught a list property in each node and see if it appears in other node property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data in Neo4j looking like this: (ARTICLE) and (TOPIC) nodes.

In each ARTICLE nodes I have a property that contains a list of strings like this, the property is topics:

"topics": ["sun", "sky"]

I have a lot of topics nodes and I would like to create a relation between ARTICLE nodes and TOPICS nodes every time the string correponding to the name of a TOPIC node.

For example if I have a TOPIC node with the property topic and the value sun, I would like to create a relationship between article containing the string sun (in the topics list property of ARTICLE nodes) and TOPIC nodes.

How can I do this ? I thought about looping in every list of nodes and see if it is in topic nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all articles topics then for each topic, find the corresponding topic node. Create a relationship CONNECTED_TO (or create your own name).

```
MATCH (a:ARTICLE)
UNWIND a.topics as articleTopic
MATCH (t:TOPICS {topic: articleTopic})
MERGE p=(a)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(t)
RETURN p
```

Sample result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you :) @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ